# JavaScriptのlocaleCompareで平仮名/カタカナを区別したい

Tags: javascript

JSのString.prototype.localeCompareを使うと、日本語環境では`"あ".localeCompare("ア")`が0に、その他環境では-1になります。
比較対象が「何語のどんな文字」か分かりません。(=第二引数を使えない)、
これを「カタカナとひらがなを全環境で違うものとしてみる」ようにできないでしょうか。

単純比較でできないことはないと思いますが、元のコードがlocaleCompareを使っているので、相応の理由があるのでは、とは思っています。

Comment: 「どうすればいい」のかは、「どのようになってほしい」のかによります。「単純比較もできない」理由は何なのでしょうか? どの言語環境でも同じ結果を得たいということなのでしょうか? もう少し詳しく自分がどんな比較を行いたいのかご説明いただけませんか?

Comment: ご質問内容の更新ありがとうございました。ただ、「単純比較でできないことはないと思います」「元のコードがlocaleCompareを使っている」では、「カタカナとひらがなを全環境で違うものとしてみる」以外の違いが元のコードで予期しない範囲に及んでしまう可能性があります。例えば、`localeCompare`を「英大文字小文字を区別しない比較」のつもりで使っておられる方々がおられます(誤った使い方なわけですが、結構使われていたりします)が、「半角英字の大文字小文字は区別しないが、カタカナとひらがなは区別する」といった程度まででも比較の仕様を規定できないでしょうか。今のままだと「単純比較ならどんな環境でもカタカナとひらがなは区別されますよ」なんて回答になってしまいます。

Comment: わかりました。いったん開発者に聞きたいのでこの質問をクローズしたいのですが、どうしたらいいですか?

Comment: このサイトにはユーザ主導でのクローズはなかったはずなんで、運営側に依頼するか、一旦削除してもらうことになるでしょう。今回の場合、私以外からのコメントもついていませんし、いったん削除した上で再度投稿(または編集して削除取り消し)していただく形で問題無いと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

結局、単純に`<`、`==`、`>`の演算子でよかったことがわかりました。
ありがとうございます。